# Open Firefox Webdriver with Adblock Plus Extension (Python)

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver, adblock

I want to open Firefox with Python Webdriver and the Adblock Plus Extension.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
ffprofile.add_extension(extension='adblock.xpi')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=ffprofile)
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "adblock_test.py", line 6, in 
>       ffprofile.add_extension(extension='adblock.xpi')
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile
>   .py", line 92, in add_extension
>       self._install_extension(extension)
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile
>   .py", line 269, in _install_extension
>       addon_details = self._addon_details(addon)
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile
>   .py", line 341, in _addon_details
>       manifest = f.read()
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
>       return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 964: char
>   acter maps to undefined

Other Extensions work with exactly this code without problems.
Only the Adblock Plus Extension (https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) doesn't work.
Anyone knows a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is adblock plus manifest file contains some unicode characters.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Change code in selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py

   `with open(os.path.join(addon_path, 'install.rdf'), 'r') as f:`

to `with open(os.path.join(addon_path, 'install.rdf'), 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:`

2. Download adblock_plus.xpi and remove localization strings from manifest (You can open .xpi with any archive manager)

Also this is an issue you can submit a ticket to selenium bug tracker so it is resolved in selenium itself.

Comment: Thanks, I just submit the ticket: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/527

Comment: Can you clarify how to "remove localization strings from manifest"